# Logging SQL warnings in MariaDB

Tags: mariadb

Is there a way to log SQL warnings on a MariaDB server (10.2)?

For example, I would like to be able to record (in a log file) this type of warning (strict mode is disabled in this example):

```
MariaDB [mysql]> select now() = 1;
+-----------+
| now() = 1 |
+-----------+
|         0 |
+-----------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [mysql]> show warnings;
+---------+------+-------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                       |
+---------+------+-------------------------------+
| Warning | 1292 | Incorrect datetime value: '1' |
+---------+------+-------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: The commandline tool?  Or some other client?

Comment: no, not the client, but the server... something like MariaDB SQL_ERROR_LOG plugin or a builtin option if any...

Answer (score 1):

If you're OK with using strict mode so that warnings are converted to errors, then you can use the MariaDB [SQL Error Log Plugin](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/sql-error-log-plugin/) to log these into a special SQL error log file:

```
INSTALL SONAME 'sql_errlog'; 
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode';
```

gives:

> STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION

So we have strict mode (`STRICT_TRANS_TABLES`), which means this will produce an error instead of a warning (`title` is `varchar(5)`):

```
INSERT INTO t1 (id, title) VALUES (1, 'foobar');
```

Yes, we get:

> ERROR 1406 (22001): Data too long for column 'title' at row 1

... and then that error can be found in the SQL error log at `/var/lib/mysql/sql_errors.log`.

(Note that the example in the question will not produce an error even in strict mode as it doesn't affect a table. As it's not an error it won't be logged to the SQL error log.)

Answer (score 0):

Starting with 5.7.2, use [log_error_verbosity](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_log_error_verbosity)

Before that, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_log_warnings -- which probably does not do what you wanted.

For MariaDB, use [log_warnings=2](https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/what-exactly-does-logwarnings2-log).  See `log_warnings` in [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/server-system-variables/)

Comment: From what I know, log_warnings only log server administration warnings, not SQL query execution warnings...

Comment: @NicolasPayart - then there is no log of the Warnings.