# Show a Warning on logon in MariaDB

Tags: mariadb, my.cnf

I pretend to show a personalized message at login in MariaDB ver. 10.1.37 , in accordance with the data in one table.

My idea was to use a stored procedure as shown in [fromdual.com](https://www.fromdual.com/mysql-logon-and-logoff-trigger-for-auditing) but i can't find the my.cnf in my disk (I'm using Xampp), so i created the file and added `SET GLOBAL init_connect="CALL audit.login_trigger()";` but now I have this error:

> error: Found option without preceding group in config file:
>   C:\xampp\mysql\my.cnf at line: 1 Fatal error in defaults handling.
>   Program aborted

Q1)What preceding group should I type?
In this [pdf](https://www.fromdual.com/sites/default/files/logon_trigger_wp.pdf) from fromdual there is no details on this topic.

Q2) is there any other method? 
I have look in to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/436474/is-it-possible-to-change-the-mysql-welcome-message) but I need to check the tables to create the message

This [same question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/192932/logging-sql-warnings-in-mariadb) has been made in server fault, but I think that this site is more adequate.

Comment: You error is asking about `C:\xampp\mysql\my.cnf` so what is its contents? What exactly is MariaDB ver 15? 10.4 is still in beta so it hasn't reached 15 yet.

Comment: Hi @danblack;
1st) I have corrected the version (I had that number on the top of my mind) my apologies.
2nd) the question in other words is - What is preceding group that should be in the `my.cnf file` before the `SET GLOBAL init_connect="CALL audit.login_trigger()";` option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your my.cnf file should have:

```
[mysqld]
init_connect="CALL audit.login_trigger()"
```

Or any other group name from running `mysqld --help --verbose`, there's a line like `The following groups are read: mysqld server mysqld-10.1 mariadb mariadb-10.1 client-server galera`, so any of those groups be can used instead of `[mysqld]`.

`SET GLOBAL ...` is for setting mysqld system variables at runtime. The config file takes the shorter form.

Comment: thank you @danblack;
Your help was most appreciated the init_connect now shows as the SP required.
But it doesn't run as expected. I login with a normal user and did:
1) `show global variables like 'init%';`  - OK -
2) `CALL mydb.warnings();` - OK -
3) quit - Login - no result back to 1)
what i'm missing?

Comment: Sounds like a new question that would involve showing the procedure contents and what results actually are. Probably would be the `SECURITY [DEFINER|INVOKER]` aspects of the procedure and who was the definer.

Comment: Well the definition is `DEFINER='root'@'localhost'`
I have made [this question here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/232320/init-connect-not-executing).
For future readers that use Xampp, I was able to do the sugested config in 'my.ini' accessible by it's control panel.

Comment: Drawback:  `root` (or any `SUPER` user) skips the `init_connect` command.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. Just did it, but the behavior is the same.
The  DEFINER=`'tk3'@'localhost'`  this user as a grant to `select` and `call`. It's the same one for the the login  test.