# init_connect not executing

Tags: stored-procedures, mariadb, trigger, logins

From this [question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/231785/show-a-warning-on-logon-in-mariadb/232075?noredirect=1#comment458525_232075) I was able to make my  `init_connect =  "CALL mydb.Warnings()"`, but a user login in does not triggers the SP.

the SP is like:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Warnings`()
BEGIN
select * from mydb.log;
END
```

The user 'Tk3' is able to call the SP with success, but it ain't allowed to do Selects. 
I did check with `show global variables like 'init_%';` and the correct value is set.

I'm missing the reason for this failure, could you help?

**1st Edit:**
After the @danblack and  @Rick-James suggestions I altered the SECURITY to:
`CREATE DEFINER='tk3'@'localhost' PROCEDURE 'warnings'()` 
but the behavior is the same. 
:( I'm lost ):

**2nd Edit:**

```
    MariaDB [(none)]> show create procedure logdatabase.warnings;
    +-----------+--------------------------------------------+----------------------+
    | Procedure | sql_mode    
    |Create Procedure  
    |character_set_client | collation_connection | Database Collation |
    +-----------+--------------------------------------------+----------------------+
    | warnings  | NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |

    CREATE DEFINER=`tk3`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `warnings`()
    BEGIN

    SELECT * FROM logdatabase.log_activity;
    END 
    | utf8                 | utf8_general_ci      | latin1_swedish_ci  |
    +-----------+--------------------------------------------+----------------------+
    1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

```
MariaDB [(none)]> show grants for 'tk3'@'localhost';
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for tk3@localhost                                                     |                           
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'tk3'@'localhost'                                      |   
| GRANT SELECT, CREATE, EXECUTE, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE ON `logdatabase`.* TO 'tk3'@'localhost' |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I'm not showing the SHOW CREATE USER because it's returning an error:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> CREATE USER 'mytest'@'localhost';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> show CREATE USER 'mytest'@'localhost';
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'USER 'mytest'@'localhost'' at line 1
```

(this print was made with 'root' - I will deal with this strange thing later)

Comment: Check the spelling of "tigers".  Do you have "connection pooling".  `init_connect` is ignored by `root`.

Comment: You seem to be trying to call a procedure called `SP_Warnings`, but the procedure you've created is named `Warnings`.

Comment: @rick-james: thanks for the notice. I think I don't have pooling. This is a Xampp vanilla  installation, and the login is made in the cmd with mysql.exe -utk3.... @dbemon: The naming error was just a consequent of a bad renaming. the `CALL` stored in the `init_connect` runs ok (tested with copy-paste + `;`)

Comment: What's the full `SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE Warnings` because you haven't listed the `SQL SECURITY` characteristic. What is `SHOW CREATE USER Tk3` and `SHOW GRANTS FOR TK3'

Comment: Hi @danblack;
Sorry for my late reply. I must have misinterpreted the SQL Security characteristic.
I have added the information, all but the SHOW CREATE USER .